# How to attach a file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to attach a file in Codeigniter mail class?

```
 <input type="file" class="default" name="attach">
```

In my controller:

```
$this->load->library('email');
                $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                $this->email->from('admin@admin.com'); 
                $this->email->to($emailid);// change it to yours
                $this->email->subject($subject);
                $this->email->message($message);
                $this->email->attach();
                $this->email->send();
```

I dont know what to give inside the attach().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow this url for email reference in codeigniter [email sending with codeIgniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo1.jpg');
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo2.jpg');
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo3.jpg');

$this->email->send();
```

Comment: how to get the path? is it a local system file path or  i have to upload it to server and get that path?

Comment: where is your project ??? if it is on local system then local file path or if it is on server then server path.

Comment: how to get the local file path?

Comment: use <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/path/to/your/folder

Comment: if the file is in desktop means?

Comment: file should be on server. if it is on desktop then upload it first on local server .because when you will make it live the file should be on server.

Comment: may i use base_url instead of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ??

Comment: if it contains document path then you can use. document path like "/var/www/check/file.jpg" you can use base_url

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter PATH of the attachment in attach function like `$this->email->attach('/path/to/attachment');`

And if you want to add more than one file repeat the same line.

Note that path should not be URL.

Comment: how to get the path? is it a local system file path or  i have to upload it to server and get that path?

Comment: path is relative to the index.php file. You can just add `$this->email->attach('./uploadfolder/filename.ext');`

Comment: if my file is in desktop or some other folder means what do to?

Comment: Than you can define absolute path `$this->email->attach('c:/foldername/filename.ext');`

Answer (score 0):

Use This:-

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo1.jpg');
```

[Click On This link for Full details about email function](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)